# How do i submit mulitple forms, using the same action, using a single button

Tags: php, html

So, I have looked through the forum, and not found a case similar to mine on this topic.

I am trying to create a form that gives  9 options, each option with 2 choices, which give a total of 18 possibilities. The final 9 options, I would like to then submit, via post method, to a php file, which will then use that information to update an sql database.

I have got to this point in my code, and have not been able to find, or bring together the elements I need to make it work.

```
    <table border="2">
  <tr> <td colspan="2" align="center">Game 1</td></tr>
  <form>  <tr height="40px"><td><input type="radio" name="Game1" value="Home"/> Home </td><td><input type="radio" name="Game1" value="Away" /> Away</td></tr></form>
 <tr> <td colspan="2" align="center">Game 2</td></tr>
<form><tr height="40px"><td><input type="radio" name="Game2" value="Home" /> Home</td><td><input type="radio" name="Game2" value="Away" /> Away </td></tr></form>
```

Game 3
          Home Away 
            Game 4
   Home Away 
            Game 5
   Home Away 
            Game 6
   Home Away 
            Game 7
   Over Under 
            Game 8
   Over Under 
            Game 9
   Over Under

```
</table>
<input type="button" value="Muli-submit" onclick="$('.form').submit()" />
```

Now I am not sure, that this is the correct functionality, so the idea is a one button the submits each of the 9 forms, which will be values for each of the games to something like this:

```
<form action="update9.php" method="post">
```

Thus creating a list of values that will be used in the php as such:

```
  <?php 
$Member=$_POST["member"];
$Game1=$_POST["Game1"];
$Game2=$_POST["Game2"];
$Game3=$_POST["Game3"];
$Game4=$_POST["Game4"];
$Game5=$_POST["Game5"];
$Game6=$_POST["Game6"];
$Game7=$_POST["Game7"];
$Game8=$_POST["Game8"];
$Game9=$_POST["Game9"];





// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("efootyonline.ipagemysql.com", "user", Password") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("web_footy1") or die(mysql_error());

 // The SQL statement is built
 $strSQL = "UPDATE Round_9 SET "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game1= '$Game1', ";
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game2= '$Game2', "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game3= '$Game3', "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game4= '$Game4', "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game5= '$Game5', "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game6= '$Game6', "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game7= '$Game7', "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game8= '$Game8', "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "Game9= '$Game9' "; 
$strSQL = $strSQL . "WHERE  Member = '$Member' "; 

// The SQL statement is executed 
mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error()) ;

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();

?>
```

## The database is updated!

Thanks in advance. I am self taught, about 2 months into developing and refine this site as a work in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to have separate forms.  Just use 1 form..!

```
<table border="2">
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Game 1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr height="40px">
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game1" value="Home"/> Home</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game1" value="Away"/> Away</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Game 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="40px">
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game2" value="Home"/> Home</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game2" value="Away"/> Away</td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Also, it will probably be easier to work with the info if you load the values for each game into an array rather than having separate variables.

You can do this by naming the elements and specifying the index in brackets `Game[1]`.

So using:

```
<table border="2">
    <form method="POST" action="http://eqtracker.com/testing.php">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Game 1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr height="40px">
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game[1]" value="Home"/> Home</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game[1]" value="Away"/> Away</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Game 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="40px">
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game[2]" value="Home"/> Home</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game[2]" value="Away"/> Away</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Game 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="40px">
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game[3]" value="Home"/> Home</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Game[3]" value="Away"/> Away</td>
        </tr>
        <button type="submit">Submit the Info</button>
    </form>
</table>
```

Would get you a single array called `Game` loaded up with all the values.

```
array(1) {
  ["Game"]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Home"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Away"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Home"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh.. Of course... When i originally tried it i hadnt defined game by game so i couldn't seperate the radio inputs... Thanks heaps

Comment: No problem..!  Also, you may find it easier to load all the data into an array.  see updated answer.. :-)

Comment: Awesome,  this however would affect the input in the php file... And is there a way to drop strings from array if no value is selected... Ie allowing the abilty to update 1 game at a time

Comment: You are right, it will affect the input... that was sort of the idea, to make it easier to work with in that PHP! (which may not be the case if you've already done all the work on that PHP).

So, only elements that are selected will be posted.  items with no selection will not get passed to your PHP.

Comment: Oh, so the array will automatically collapse itself.. Quick question tho,  if $gameX is not defined in update.php, will it then update the db for that game as nothing,  therefore erasing possible previous selection?

Comment: you should construct your query in a way that it is only executing things with data that actually gets passed in.  This is why it is helpful to have all your info in an array.  You can loop through the array and either build the query or execute a query for each piece of data passed in.